# Showing DialogFragment without the calling Activity as background

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I am using the `AlarmManager` to pass a `PendingIntent` to my `BroadcastReceiver` after, say, 5 minutes. Now, I want to show a `DialogFragment` to the user, on top of whatever app the user might be using when the alarm goes off. For example, if the user is using Chrome when the alarm goes off, my `DialogFragment` should popup ABOVE the user's Chrome window.

What I am ending up with instead, is the `DialogFragment` being shown with a blank activity of my app as the background (as in the following pic)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz9IZ.png

This is the code I am using in my `BroadcastReceiver`, to launch an `FragmentActivity` first :

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Intent hardReminderIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmHardActivity.class);
            hardReminderIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(hardReminderIntent);

        }
}
```

Next, from this activity, I am popping up the `DialogFragment` :

```
public class AlarmHardActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        AlarmHardDialog editNameDialog = new AlarmHardDialog();
        editNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_dialog");
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_hard);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_alarm_hard, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**My questions :**

1. I could not find a way to call `getSupportFragmentManager` directly from the `onReceive` in my `BroadcastReceiver`, and thus assumed that the only way to obtain a dialog, would be to first call a 'dummy' activity, that creates the dialog. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Irrespective of whether or not my approach was correct, I expected that since there is no call to `setContentView(..)` in AlarmHardActivity, there would be no UI rendered for it. Is my understanding wrong? I also tried calling `setContentView(..)` and then marking the layout to have `Theme.NoDisplay` and `android:alpha="0"`, but to no avail.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of showing dialog on the activity, better alternative will be making activity look like dialog by using dialog theme and setting margin of all sides to desirable dp, so that activity get shrieked to dialog box size.

For few examples look at these posts:
[Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

[Android: how to create a transparent dialog-themed activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070505/android-how-to-create-a-transparent-dialog-themed-activity)

[How to set a dialog themed activity width to screen width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961833/how-to-set-a-dialog-themed-activity-width-to-screen-width)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Also, to ensure that clicks outside the activity didn't cause it to close, I used the answer from this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028842/how-to-check-if-i-have-touched-inside-or-outside-of-a-modal-activity
Cheers! Would still be interesting to know why my approach didn't work though..

Answer (score 3):

To your questions:

1. Fragments can be attached only to `Activity` (`ActivityFragment`). So yes, you need dummy `Activity` for this.
2. Use the invisible theme `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, calling setContentView isn't necessary. But this theme isn't Holo compatible (in dialog you would have old Android look). I solved this with custom theme (I use this from `ICS`, but it should work from `HONEYCOMB`):

```xml
<style name="InvisibleTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <!-- Note that we use the base animation style here (that is no animations) because we really have no idea how this kind of activity will be used. -->
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to show this dialog without Activity. You can try to run your app like you have on your screenshoot, but with transparent background and hidden ActionBar. But i have never tried to do that so I'm not sure if it will work.